# Непонятная ошибка ERROR 1062 SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Немогу понять с чем связано. Есть таблица:
 id int
 name string
 message string

к ней выполняеться простой запрос

```
INSERT INTO table (name, message) VALUES ("Gosha", "didnt drink")
```

Выход
    Error 1062: Duplicate entry 'Gosha-didnt drink' for key 'tid_pid_name_unique'

Comment: У вас есть некий уникальный ключ  `tid_pid_name_unique`, видимо состоящий из указанных двух полей и в БД уже есть точно такая же запись. с Gosha и didnt drink

Comment: Самое интересное что такого в бд нету.

Comment: посмотрите описания таблиц. это может быть как ограничение уникальности, так и уникальный индекс

Comment: например поищите в констраинтах `select *
from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where lower(CONSTRAINT_NAME) = 'tid_pid_name_unique'`

Comment: или вы записи не видите, тогда это странно. она должна быть

Comment: Списобо, что то такое действительно есть,будем копать в этом направлении